# Check if string matches a particular format

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a string defined as:

```
char *str
```

How can I check to validate if the string matched the format:

```
x-y-z
```

Where x, y and z are all of type **int**.

For Example: the string `1-2-4` should be valid while `"1-2*3"`, `"1-2"`, `"1-2-3-4"` are Invalid.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did, or didn't, that work? What problems do you have with your program? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using plain C only, or is for example a regular expression library an option?

Comment: I think you should use a regular expression to match your string. Do some google search about it and you will find plenty of examples Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more info than just the matching, then you could walk through the string using a loop. I'll give you some starter code.

```
int i = 0;
int correct = 1;
int numberOfDashes = 0;
while(correct && i < strlen(str)) {
  if(isdigit(str[i])) {

  }
  else {
     if(str[i] == '-') {
        numberOfDashes++;
     }
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of achieving what you want is to use `scanf()` and check the returned value. Something like

```
  ret = scanf("%d-%d-%d", &x, &y, &z);
  if (ret == 3) {// match};
```

would do fine for a simple approach.

This approach won't work for multiple data types and longer inputs, though, only for a fixed format. For a more complex scenario, you may want to consider using a regex library.

Comment: (Perhaps better suggest `sscanf`?)

Answer (score 0):

Along the line with Sourav's answer.

```
int check( char t[] )
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    return sscanf( t, "%d-%d-%d-%d", &a, &b, &c, &d ) == 3;
}


int main()
{
    char s[] = "1-2-4";
    char t[] = "1-2-3-4";
    printf( "s = %s, correct format ? %s\n", s, check( s ) ? "true" : "false" );  // <-- true
    printf( "t = %s, correct format ? %s\n", s, check( t ) ? "true" : "false" );  // <-- false
}
```

Comment: test as `"1-2-4-"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf` for your specific string example.

```
int main()
{    
  int x,y,z;
  char *str="1-2-4";  
  int a = sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d", &x, &y, &z);
  printf( "%s", (a == 3) ? "Correct format":"Incorrect format");

  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/SsatMF)</kbd>

while the `sscanf` format won't work for these specified strings:

```
int main()
{    
  int x,y,z;
  char *str="1-2*3";  //or "1-2" or ""1-2-3-4""   
  int a = sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d", &x, &y, &z);
  printf( "%s", (a == 3) ? "Correct format":"Incorrect format");

  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/Vf9m5g)</kbd>

For circumventing this, you need to use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) as the others have already said.