# Enter values in one line (STDIN)

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct called Person:

```cpp
Person
{
  int id;
  int age;
  int salary;
};
```

So I want to enter as many Person as I want with the standard input in one line of the following form:

`[id, age, salary] [id, age, salary] ...`

So I did write this code but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for:

```cpp
std::vector<Person> person;
int y = scanf("%i", &num);
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    Person p;
    int r = scanf("[%i,%i,%i]", &p.id, &p.age, &p.salary);
    person.push_back(p);
}
```

How can I correct my code to satisfy my need?

Comment: What's the value of `r` and why are you using `scanf`?

Comment: Google `std::cin`

Comment: because I want the following format [ , , ]

Comment: Can you spot the difference between [1](https://godbolt.org/z/a97rYqzaj) and [2](https://godbolt.org/z/deqn1K61K) (or [3](https://godbolt.org/z/c57313rc1))?

Comment: oh why the value of r is changed?

Comment: Probably there is a space or a newline in your input, one that is not taken into account by the format string your code passed to `scanf`. Try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Yj5cxerqn) and then I'd suggest you to search for safer alternatives.

Comment: thanks, and how to verify if I entered { instead of [
I want the program to give me an error if so

Comment: Well, there are plenty of ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977400/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-format-is-valid-while-reading-from-a-text-file-in-c/51977833  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672532/check-if-string-matches-a-particular-format  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276482/how-to-check-if-users-input-is-valid-c , starting from checking the value returned by `scanf`, which is the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::cin instead of scanf:

```
std::vector<Person> person;
int y;
std::cin >> y;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    Person p;
    std::cin >> p.id >> p.age >> p.salary;
    person.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: This accepts `id age salary id age salary ...` instead of `[id, age, salary] [id, age, salary] ...`